# Reprojection changes resolution QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, resolution

I have US National Atlas (EPSG:2163) file having resolution of 250 m, 250 m that I want to reproject to EPSG:4326 with the same pixel size as the original map. Using

`gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:2163 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of Gtiff "projected.tif" "reprojected.tif"`,

converts the pixel size to '0.00436162,-0.00436162' which is much more area than USNatAtlas pixel area. Why is this error taking place and can I have a work around for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the `-tr` option? I guess that gdalwarp calculates a square pixel size, while the unprojected original cells will become rectangles.

Comment: The unit in EPSG:2163 is meter. The unit in EPSG:4326 is grad.

Comment: Can you point one such Atlas map file for testing?